# Why AWS cognito asks me to which appclient to use everytime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS cognito for authentication purpose.

Every time i hit the cognito domain name it asks me to select the the App client.

[image: Cognito appclient select screen]

Is there a way i can stop cognito asking me to select the Appclient i want to use for authentication.

please do let me know the way

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot that you have posted asks you to select the user with whom you'd like to log in, and it has nothing to do with the App Client. Every App Client of a User Pool works with the same set of users in the pool, but with different authentication settings. If you want to select the App Client for your Cognito Authentication Engine, you can specify the App Client ID in your Cognito Hosted UI Domain. An [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html) URL is as follows:

```
https://auth.example.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=<your_app_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_callback_url>
```

If you specify the App Client ID in your Hosted UI Domain/Custom Domain, you can run your Engine only on that App Client.

Answer (score 0):

The text following after the "Continue with" text is not the app client but your logged-in username.

After you login with your username-password credentials, a session cookie will be set on your Cognito domain to indicate you are already logged in. This session cookie expiration is not configurable and set to 1 hour expiration. The **Logout Endpoint** removes this session cookie.

When you re-enter the Cognito login page, it will detect you already have a session and present you with the "Continue with" page to confirm that you want to still continue as this user.

If you want to dodge this screen. You can use the **Authorization Endpoint** which will first check if you have the Cognito domain session, and if you do, automatically redirect you to the redirect uri (application with authorization code), otherwise it will redirect you to the login form via **Login Endpoint**.

```
https://COGNITO_SUBDOMAIN.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=APP_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code
```

Authorization Endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html